# Cannot connect to socket.io in android , saying invalid namespace

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io, serversocket

[image]

When i try to connect my android app with socket.io, it saying invalid namespace. There is no issue with socket url , but having problem in connection, please help if you faced this issue ever. Thanks!

```
val options = io.socket.client.IO.Options().apply {
        forceNew = false
        reconnection = true

    }
private val socket: Socket = io.socket.client.IO.socket(socket_url,options)

val socket = applicationAccessorImpl.socket

socket.connect()


socket.once(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "connect")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.message!!)
    }
}.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {
    val e = it[0]
    Log.e(TAG, "error $e")
}.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT) {
        val e = it[0]
        Log.e(TAG, "Transport error $e")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , it was my mistake , i was passing the wrong url